# Wordpress GUI on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

**I have brought up mysql and wordpress containers on my master-minion single node of the kubernetes cluster** (I have created this setup inside my openstack cloud). But when I try to access it on my web, **it gives me a "page not found" error**.

While listing the endpoints of ther services running, I can use the docker ip to access wordpress through the elinks command.

```
$ kubectl get endpoints
NAME         ENDPOINTS
kubernetes   20.20.0.124:6443
mysql        172.17.0.2:3306
wpfrontend   172.17.0.3:80

$ elinks 172.17.0.3:80
```

**How do I access through my web GUI?**

Comment: Can you try to get into the running service itself and ensure it's running properly? That is `kubectl.sh get pods` `kubectl.sh exec <pod-name-for-wordpress> -ti bash` `# curl 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @aronchick I did try what you suggested and it looks like the container is running fine.

Comment: I agree with Abhishek's answer - I believe you may not have set up an external service endpoint.

Comment: I have a mysql.yaml and wordpress.yaml files to bring up pods. While I have other 2 files for mysql-service.yaml and wordpress-service.yaml. In the wordpress-service.yaml I have stated the 'type: LoadBalancer'.

Comment: can you try to 'kubectl get svc'? It should have both internal and external endpoints. What cloud are you working on?

Comment: I'm having my kubernetes cluster in my OpenStack cloud provider.  When I run kubectl ger svc, it's providing me the service cluster IP with ports.

Comment: Can you execute the following on your service? 'cluster/kubectl.sh get svc <YOURSERVICENAME> -o yaml'? There should be a section that says (status: -> loadBalancer: -> ingress: -> hostname:). This will have the external hostname.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the following documentation:
http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/services.html#external-services

You need to set up a load balancer to expose your Kubernetes service externally.

Comment: I have been referring the github site for kubernetes and according to the link https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/mysql-wordpress-pd, execpet that I have excluded the gce portion and I'm working on an ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a soup-to-nuts Wordpress example with backing persistent storage: https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/master/examples/wordpress.

You'll want to use Cinder volumes, though.  Here is the github pull that adds Cinder support to the Wordpress example:  https://github.com/openshift/origin/pull/4403

The example is in OpenShift, but OpenShift is based on Kube (Red Hat is a major contributor to Kube).  The example works exactly the same, you'll just substitute the OpenShift client (oc) with the Kube client (kubectl).

Like Abhishek mentioned, you need a Service.  The example above contains services that front MySQL and Wordpress.